# horizontally align and vertically center three elements in a container

Tags: html, css

I need to align 3 items inside Div.

Every item must be placed **vertically** in the center.

- First item 2% margin-left.
- Second item in the center and must be a textbox.
- Third item 2% margin-right.

Item First and Third must fit the div(square).

I used alignment but it didn't work. Here there is a graphic example:

[image]

Comment: Could you please show your code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="box" id="left"></div>
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="SEARCH HERE" id="searchbox">
    <div class="box" id="right"></div>  
</div><!-- end #container-->
```

CSS

```
#container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 95%;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: orangered;
}

.box {
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

#left {
    margin-left: 2%;
}

#right {
    margin-right: 2%;
}

input {
    width: 250px;
    padding: 18px;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/xptx9wxn/2/

[image]

For more information about CSS Flexbox visit:

- [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
- [Using CSS flexible boxes - Web developer guide | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)

Comment: Can you do this without floats and margins?  I can't get the rightmost box not to drop down a line without these exact constraints.

Comment: There are many ways to center elements. In this example I've used a flexbox and flex properties. There are no floats involved, and the only margins are the ones required in the question (otherwise, I could have also used `justify-content: space-around` for horizontal alignment).

Comment: I like this.  It is an elegant alternative to floated bloated divs.

Comment: Not to sound like a salesperson, but centering things has never been simpler and more efficient. Flexbox solves many problems that used to require much more code. Only thing to keep in mind is that flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex).

Comment: If lateral box were img how could I vertically center them?

Comment: @user4789408, the `align-items` property (which vertically centers flex items in this context) is applied to *all* child elements of the `div#container`, regardless of their type. So whether it's a `div` or an `img` you center it the same way. http://jsfiddle.net/xptx9wxn/8/